# Не могу найти ошибку в синтаксисе Python

Tags: python, syntax

Вопрос немного глупый,но без помощи я его не решу. Пишу код коллаборативной фильтрации, сам код примерно готов, однако выдаёт ошибку в синтаксисе в 3 строке. Не могу сам найти проблему и прошу помощи.
Ошибка:

```
matches = [(u, distCosine(userRates[userID], userRates[u])) for u in userRates if u <> userID]
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Код:

```
import math
def makeRecommendation (userID, userRates, nBestUsers, nBestProducts):
    matches = [(u, distCosine(userRates[userID], userRates[u])) for u in userRates if u <> userID]
    bestMatches = sorted(matches, key=lambda(x,y):(y,x), reverse=True)[:nBestUsers]
    print "Most correlated with '%s' users:" % userID
    for line in bestMatches:
        print "  UserID: %6s  Coeff: %6.4f" % (line[0], line[1])    
    sim = dict()
    sim_all = sum([x[1] for x in bestMatches])
    bestMatches = dict([x for x in bestMatches if x[1] > 0.0])        
    for relatedUser in bestMatches:
        for product in userRates[relatedUser]:
            if not product in userRates[userID]:
                if not product in sim:
                    sim[product] = 0.0
                sim[product] += userRates[relatedUser][product] * bestMatches[relatedUser]
    for product in sim:
        sim[product] /= sim_all
    bestProducts = sorted(sim.iteritems(), key=lambda(x,y):(y,x), reverse=True)[:nBestProducts]
    print "Most correlated products:"
    for prodInfo in bestProducts:    
        print "  ProductID: %6s  CorrelationCoeff: %6.4f" % (prodInfo[0], prodInfo[1])
    return [(x[0], x[1]) for x in bestProducts]
```

Comment: ... if u `!=` userID

Comment: Это по-моему только в SQL есть такой вариант написания "не равно" как <>, в языках программирования обычно !=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `python` для операция `не равен`, надо использовать `!=`

```
if u != userID
```

Answer (score 0):

Что значит <>?)
Может:

```
== - Значение равно другому
!= - значение НЕ равно другому
<= >= - Меньше или равно и больше или равно (цифры)
<, > - больше и меньше
```